# Spring Batch: write failed records in DB table

Tags: spring, spring-batch

i have to implement a Spring Batch in which i have to elaborate data coming from an input table and write the result of the elaboration in an output table... up to now ok.

I have the following requirement: if the elaboration of some records fails (either in reader, processor or writer), i have to write those records in a "failed record" table.

The question is: which is the best way to do that?

Thanks
Alessandro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supose that you are skiping failed items so a `SkipListener` will work fine.

Something like

```
public class StoreFailedRecordsSkipListener implements SkipListener<A, B> {

    @Override
    public void onSkipInRead(Throwable t) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInWrite(B item, Throwable t) {
        // save processed item
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipInProcess(A item, Throwable t) {
        // save read item
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `onSkipInRead`,  item isn't there, how to insert the record in the DB when skip on read?